# grep -v not working in solaris 10

Tags: comparison, grep

I have two files:

File 1 contains

```
Roger 
Roger
Bob
Bob
Elliot
Matt
```

File 2 contains

```
Roger
Bob
```

I need to compare both files and have the non-matching (Elliot and Matt) to be redirected to another file.

I have tried the following in Solaris 10 and it is not working, however it works fine in Linux:

```
grep -v File2 File1
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated as I have already wasted a lot of time on this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you have `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` like me on `Solaris` 11 :

```
$ cat /tmp/file
Roger 
Roger
Bob
Bob
Elliot
Matt

$ cat /tmp/filter
Roger
Bob

$ /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -f /tmp/filter -v /tmp/file
Elliot
Matt
```

Comment: If you add another occurence of "Roger" in /tmp/file it doesn't work. The results return (assuming you have a 3rd Roger) Roger, Elliot, Matt. hmmm

Comment: I don't have this behaviour with `Solaris` 5.11